# Java 8 Streams - Prepare two lists valid & invalid based on incoming comma seperated string

Tags: java, java-8

I have a requirement where i get a multiple strings separated with comma. I need to prepare two lists valid & invalid  by comparing against with base list and return to client. I'm doing like this as of now:

```
String[] nodesArr = nodesStr.split(",");
List<String> sbInvalid=new ArrayList<>();
List<String> sbValid=new ArrayList<>();
        
Arrays.stream(nodesArr).forEach(node ->{
   if(baselist.contains(node)) {
      sbValid.add(node);
   }else {
      sbInvalid.add(node);
   }
});
```

Is there any other way to do this in simple way (mostly in single iteration) using streams in java 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html)

Using [Collectors#partitioningBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-) allows you to partition the valid and invalid strings within the stream, and returns a map with both values:

```
Map<Boolean, List<String>> results = Stream.of(nodesArr).collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(baseList::contains));
List<String> sbValid = results.get(true);
List<String> sbInvalid = results.get(false);
```

The collector returns a map where the key is the boolean result of the predicate and the value is the list of the values that tested either true or false, corresponding to the predicate result.

Comment: Excellent. Java 8 Streams has lot of potential to know. :) Is there any operation i can combine to remove duplicates from the returned lists?

Comment: [.distinct()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) should do that :)